# Can an electron near thar the positive terminal of a battery make it all the way to the positive terminal?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance, conductors, batteries

Following Drude's model of conductivity, can an electron near thar the positive terminal of a battery make it all the way to the positive terminal? The electron is in the wire but near the positive terminal. At least, is it probable? Assuming that the circuit size is commonly small. The reason I asked this is that I do now know how to interpret the average velocity of an electron in this model. Because I know it bounces off impurities until reaching a stationary average velocity. Can I use this average velocity to estimate a time to go from one side to the other using the formula of uniform rectilinear motion?

Comment: This is very unclear. Is the electron in the electrolyte, or outside the battery, or in some external circuit, or what? Why would it not be able to go all the way? Please spend some effort to explain the question fully, recognizing that we cannot look inside your head and see what you don’t tell us.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it. I hope now is clear.

Comment: Yes, those edits are much better. I have voted to reopen

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe, if the circuit is small enough, and runs for long enough.

The velocity of an electron through a wire is approximately [1mm/second](https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/how-fast-does-electricity-flow/). As a result, if you have a circuit 1cm long, and you let it run for 10 seconds, then an electron that starts off at the negative end of the circuit would reach the positive end of the circuit.

Note that this velocity is different to the speed of the electrical current, which is approximately the speed of light; the reason why it's so much faster is because each moving electron creates an electric and magnetic field around itself that in turn pushes the electron in front of it forwards, which pushes the electron in front of it, and so on and so forth until the entire column of electrons is moving almost instantaneously.

Answer (score -2):

This question has no answer as electrons are indistinguishable particles.